# Como inverter uma forma em Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Olá, queria descobrir como inverter dentro do canvas (tkinter) um poligono.

```
from Tkinter import *

Tela_principal = Tk()
Tela_principal.geometry('300x300+10+300')

area_2 = Frame(bg='snow', height=200, width=200, cursor='dotbox')
fundo_area2 = Canvas(area_2, bg='OrangeRed4', height=180, width=180)
area_2.place(x=10, y=10)
fundo_area2.place(x=4, y=4)
x = 5
y = 5


forma = fundo_area2.create_polygon([
        (51 + x, 100 + y), (151 + x, 130 + y),
        (151 + x, 50 + y)],
        fill='gray35', outline='black', tag='personagem')

Tela_principal.mainloop()
```

ou seja, neste exemplo o triangulo virar para direita.
Claro, isso seria um exemplo simples. Minha intenção é inverter polígonos com inúmeros vértices.
Alguém tem alguma idéia?
Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Basta você alterar a posição **x** da ponta do triângulo para ter seu valor somado à largura do triângulo e subtrair as posições **x** das outras coordenadas pela largura do mesmo, dessa forma:

```
forma = fundo_area2.create_polygon(
    [(51 + x + 100, 100 + y), (151 + x - 100, 130 + y), (151 + x - 100, 50 + y)],
    fill='gray35', outline='black', tag='personagem'
    )
```

Se quiser, você também pode de certa forma automatizar essa tarefa criando uma variável chamada `largura` para calcular as coordenadas com base na direção desejada do triângulo. Veja este exemplo abaixo:

```
inicio = 51
largura = 100
direcao = 1 # 0 = esquerda; 1 = direita

forma = fundo_area2.create_polygon(
    [
        (inicio + largura * direcao , 100),
        (inicio + largura - largura * direcao, 130),
        (inicio + largura - largura * direcao, 50)
        ],
    fill='gray35', outline='black', tag='personagem'
    )

Tela_principal.mainloop()
```

Você também pode fazer o mesmo para altera a direção no eixo **y** (baixo-cima), basta criar uma variável de `altura` e realizar o mesmo cálculo porém na posição **y**.

Comment: Sim, em um exemplo simples resolve, no entanto um polígono com 30 vértices que me tranca.